# 2D collision resolution system

Tags: c#, console, 2d, collision

I am making a simple 2D game in the console in C# as a learning project. However I seem to be unable to come up with a decent design for a collision system.

The resolution of a collision presents the biggest problem for me.

Basically there can be any combination of the following 2 sets of effects:
1. The triggering object or tile is removed;
2. The remote object or tile is removed;
Or nothing can happen - the objects just stop moving(i.e. when both are invulnerable or something).

Any ideas towards that effect would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you got so far?  There are plenty of tutorials on 2d collision systems out there if you don't have a specific problem we can help you with.

Comment: What have you read? I have used Coutinho's great book "Dynamic Simulations of Multibody Systems" a lot several years ago and a consequent part of this one is dedicated to collision fundamentals…

Comment: My first, probably most naive idea is about assigning some properties to my object that are used to determine what to do in the event of a collision.  For example: killObject, killTile, respondAsObject, respondAsTile, invulnerable. Maybe I should have also mentioned it's a console game. I thought the tags would be enough of a pointer to that fact.

Answer (score 1):

How to detect a collision and how to respond to it are two totally different concerns and you should separate them.

The simplest way would be to have a virtual method in your base game object responding to collisions:

```
class GameObject
{
    virtual protected void OnCollision(GameObject withObject) { }
}
```

In your collision detection system, whenever two objects collide, simply raise the collision event on the two objects: `object1.OnCollision(object2);` and `object2.OnCollision(object1)`.

You will soon realise that this might become a mess at some point and will want to learn about multiple dispatch and how to emulate it on languages that don't support it.

Comment: I am well aware of the distinction between detection and resolution. The detection on a 80*25 grid is pretty straight-forward and without much need for optimization. With resolution however I don't mean in the normal sense of dealing with intersections. I haven't tried the reciprocal calls idea. What I do is a "gameObject collidesWith()" method that gives the resolveCollision method the 2 interacting parties. It decides if the move is allowed. My trouble is not even what to do when it is allowed, but how to do it. It seems to me that there is some better way to handle it than a ton of IF's.

Comment: Look for multiple dispatch then. This is probably what you are looking for. In C# you can emulate it using delegates and maps.